# Haskell SQLError with HDBC

Tags: haskell

I want to read a file with many lines and want to save them in my table.
All is fine but when it reach the last element of my first line it stop with an SqlError.

```
readLines :: FilePath -> IO ()
readLines n = 
do s <- readFile n
   mapM_ (\x -> insertbdd x $ lines s !! 1) [3..9]

insertbdd :: Int -> String -> IO ()
insertbdd _ [] = putStrLn "k"   -- pattern matching that doesn't work
insertbdd ng xs =
    do conn <- connectSqlite3 "ngram.db"
       stmt <- handleSqlError $ prepare conn "insert into n3 (seq) values (?)"
       execute stmt $ take 1 $ (map toSql) $ ngrams ng xs
       commit conn
       insertbdd ng (tail xs)

ngrams :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
ngrams n l = take (length l - (n - 1)) . map (take n) . tails $ l
```

That stop with this message

```
*** Exception: SqlError {seState = "", seNativeError = -1, seErrorMsg     = "In HDBC execute, received [] but expected 1 args."}
```

I wroted many pattern that doesn't match.

Any idea as to why this is happening?